# Not able to find the exact mouse coordinates while making a simple circle game using p5.js

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, logic, p5.js

I have used p5.js library in order to make a small circle game.

[image: Circle Game]

in which when the user clicks outside the circle, the output is:
[image: Output when mouse is clicked outside the circle]

But even when I'm clicking inside the circle, still the output says that I've clicked outside the circle.
[image: Mouse inside the circle]

here is the `index.html` file's code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> A Simple Circle Game </title>
</head>
<body>
    <p style="text-align: center"> A Simple Circle Game </b> </p>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.5.0/lib/p5.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sketch.js"></script>
    <script src="condition1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

the `sketch.js` file is as follow:

```
function setup(){
    createCanvas(500,200).center();
    noStroke();
    background(230);
    circle(250,100,100);
}

function draw() {
  // Draw a circle
  fill(240, 204, 0);
  circle(mouseX, mouseY, 5);
}
```

the `condition1.js` file is as follows:

```
function mousePressed() {
  dist = Math.sqrt(250 * 250 + 100 * 100);
  if (mouseX > 566  && mouseX < 666 && mouseY < 258  && mouseY > 158 ) {
    document.write("You clicked the circle!");
  } else {
    document.write("You clicked outside the circle!");
  }
}
```

In the above code, in the *if* condition, shall I use any other logic or is there any else issue due to which my game isn't behaving in the way it ought to be?

I tried changing the dimensions of mouseX and mouseY but all in vain. SSo, I'm expecting a better approach towards my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *condition1.js* file should look like this. I used the [p5.Vector](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector) for the circle position, but you can change it if you want. To be clear, the squaring is skipped to make it a bit faster.

```js
function mousePressed(event)
{
  let distanceX = event.clientX - circlePos.x;
  let distanceY = event.clientY - circlePos.y;

  if (distanceX * distanceX + distanceY * distanceY < (circleRadius * circleRadius))
  {
    document.write("You clicked the circle!");
  }
  else
  {
    document.write("You clicked outside the circle!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function mousePressed()
{
  if(dist(mouseX,mouseY, Circle.x, Circle.y) <= Circle.Radius)
  {
    //DO THING HERE
  }
}
```

P5.js has a built in distance function, it uses square root so its a little slow, but it gets the job done.

Comment: Yeah surely, it's working now. Thanks but can you explain what do you mean by saying square root makes it slow...? I guess you're talking about the time it takes when some certain huge input is given to it. Is it so?

Comment: Square root is just overall, a very slow operation. But since you're not checking the mouse position every frame it should be 100% fine.